# dateFromComponents defaults to 8:00 AM

Tags: ios, swift, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I'm trying to understand how `NSCalendar` and its components work in `Swift`. I extracted components from a date, changed the components properties, and reconstructed the date. I was expecting to get `Sept 9, 2015, 12:00 AM` but
instead got `Sept 9, 2015, 8:00 AM`.

Why is the hour component at 8:00AM?

```
let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
calendar?.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")!

let components = calendar?.components([.Year, .Month, .Day, .Hour, .Minute, .Second], fromDate: NSDate())

components?.year            // 2016
components?.month        // 9
components?.day            // 9
components?.hour          // 4
components?.minute      // 31
components?.second      // 54

components?.year = 2015
components?.month = 9
components?.day = 9
components?.hour = 0
components?.minute = 0
components?.second = 0

calendar?.dateFromComponents(components!) // Sept 9, 2015, 8:00 AM
```

the code above is not meant for any use-case. it's just me trying to understand how `NSCalendar`, `NSDateComponents`, and `NSDate` are linked together.

Comment: How are you looking at the date? What timezone is shown for the date output? This is probably a non-issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you print it you will get the correct date, the NSDate is `Sept 9, 2015, 8:00 AM` is because you set the time zone to GMT, it will return date as `"Sep 9, 2015, 12:00 AM"` if you change your time zone to `NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()`